# UML Class Diagram - Is it bad practice for lines to cross?

Tags: uml

Is it bad practice for lines between different classes to cross in a UML diagram? Is it a design smell? Does it indicate that your classes are too tangled or independent or anything? Is it always/generally unavoidable? Or am I overthinking this?

Here is my current UML diagram if interested. You will see that I routed a couple lines all the way around to avoid overlapping....

[image]

Comment: In which program did you make the diagram?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it bad practice for lines between different classes to cross

Yes, because it can impede understanding of the graph/diagram.

> Is it always/generally unavoidable

Not all graphs are planar (see planarity testing), so sometimes it is unavoidable.

**But** the problem is not as simple as "I will just route the line around". There are many rules and recommendations that constitute a good layout or contribute to good visual aesthetics; to name just a few:

- lines crossing (you might have seen in some diagrams a small *bridge* when lines are crossing)
- number of line bends
- total line length
- hierarchy (typically inheritance lines should be drawn upwards)

You can already see that some of the rules are competing; so **layouting is always a balancing act**. If you are interested in more detail I suggest googling around for "graph aesthetics" or "automatic (graph) layouting".

Unfortunately most research papers I have are behind paywall, so I cannot link to the pdfs, but some of it can be google-able; e.g. [UML Diagram Layouting: the State of the Art](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/acss.2011.44.issue--1/v10143-011-0027-0/v10143-011-0027-0.xml) or [Aesthetics of Class Diagrams](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/760d/3afd3794dd148592393cf22ba5d189f80e09.pdf)

Comment: I second the bridge approach!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, line crossings may be unavoidable, but often, it happens when I am trying to show too many things with a single diagram. I see this as a "communication" smell rather than as a design smell.

I often found that explicitly writing down the question I am trying to answer helps spot the model elements that are not strictly necessary and that I should omit. Besides, several diagrams may better convey an idea/design than a single saturated one.

In your example, you could maybe break down your diagram following the colored areas you already identified.

Answer (score 1):

When ever there are crossing lines, it is a good time to stop and think if the diagram has grown to be too complex.

I feel your diagram is trying to be abstract and concrete at the same time. I see it as being too complex. It is abstract in the sense that it provides an architectural overview, and concrete in that it shows structural detail related to implementation.

Personally, I might split your diagram into a component diagram; then express each component's structure using separate class diagrams.